# $\phi \in L^1 \iff m(\{\phi \neq 0\})<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let  $\phi$ be a positive, simple, function. Prove $\phi \in L^1 \iff m(\{\phi \neq 0\})<\infty$.

---

My attempt: $(\iff)$

$\{\phi \neq 0\}=\{\phi >0\}\cup \{\phi <0\}.$

Suppose $\phi :E\to [0,+\infty),$ then $\int_{E}\phi \:dμ =\int_{\{\phi >0\}\cup \{\phi <0\}\cup \{\phi = 0\}}\phi \:dμ=
\int_{\{\phi >0\}}\phi \:dμ+\int_{\{\phi <0\}}\phi \:dμ+ \int_{\{\phi =0\}}\phi \:dμ.$

$\phi $ is integrable at $\{\phi =0\}$, so in order to $\phi \in L^1(E)$ it must be that

$\int_{\{\phi >0\}}\phi \:dμ< \infty$ and $\int_{\{\phi <0\}}\phi \:dμ<\infty,$

but because $\phi$ is simple ($\int_{\{\phi >0\}}\phi \:dμ =\sum a_im(\{\phi >0\})$ that means $m(\{\phi <0\})<\infty $, $m(\{\phi >0\})<\infty \Rightarrow m(\{\phi \neq 0\})<\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this step is incorrect.

> $\int_{\{\phi >0\}}\phi \:dμ =\sum a_im(\{\phi >0\})$

It should be
$$
\int_{\{\phi >0\}}\phi \:dμ =\sum_{i=1}^n a_im(A_i)
$$
with $a_i>0$ and $a_i\neq a_j$ for $i\neq j$. This is finite iff $m(A_i)<\infty~\forall i$. As their disjoint union is
$$
\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n A_i=\{\phi>0\},
$$
we obtain that $m\left(\{\phi>0\}\right)<\infty$ iff $\int_{\{\phi >0\}}\phi \:d\mu<\infty$. Idem for $\{\phi <0\}$, concluding the proof.